# Can't store QIcon in private class member

Tags: c++, qt, qicon

I have model inherited from QAbstractItemModel:

```
class Plugin: public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit Plugin(QObject *parent=0);
    ~Plugin();

    const QIcon icon();
    void setIcon(const QString &ico);
private:
    QIcon mIcon;
};

class PluginsModel: public QAbstractItemModel
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit PluginsModel(QObject *parent=0);
    ~PluginsModel();
protected:
    QList<Plugin*> mList;
};
```

I want to create QIcon instance only once and in data just do:

```
QVariant PluginsModel::data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const
{
    if (mList.isEmpty())
        return QVariant();

    Plugin *it = static_cast<Plugin*>(index.internalPointer());
    switch (role ) {
    case Qt::DecorationRole:
        switch (index.column()) {
        case 0:
            return it->icon();
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }

    return QVariant();
}
```

So setIcon function looks like:

```
const QIcon Plugin::icon()
{
    return mIcon;
}

void Plugin::setIcon(const QString &ico)
{
    mIcon = QIcon(ico);
}
```

And usage:

```
Plugin *p = new Plugin(this);
p->setIcon(":/images/16/amarok.png");
mPlugins->add(p);
```

The problem is that it doesn't work (icon is not drawed). But if I change setIcon to:

```
void Plugin::setIcon(QIcon &ico)
{
    mIcon = ico;
}
```

... and usage to:

```
Plugin *p = new Plugin(this);
QIcon i(":/images/16/amarok.png");
p->setIcon(i);
mPlugins->add(p);
```

... then it is working fine. Anyone can tell me what is a difference between passing QIcon reference from outside and creating reference inside class from image path argument?

Comment: Try: qDebug() << "ICO:" << ico; in `void Plugin::setIcon(const QString &ico)` as the first entity.

Comment: Well, it showing me exactly what I'm passing: ICO:  ":/images/16/amarok.png". I have also tried with mIcon.addFile(ico); instead of mIcon = QIcon(ico) but then my app is crashing

Comment: Then, I have no clue. :) Are you sure you made a clean trial again because it feels like it should work unless I am missing something.

Comment: Yes, I'm clearing and rebuilding project

Comment: Does it work if you use relative or absolute paths to a file on your system rather than a resource file? Say, just "foo.png" in the application directory.

Comment: Yes, with file it is working fine. I thought that maybe I'm creating it too fast but even after moving this to button click same problem. With file it is working but when closing app I get error "corrupted double-linked list: 0x000000000187dfa0 ***" in qt creator. Maybe I should use pointers, something like: QIcon *mIcon

Comment: Can you provide a minimal compilable example? This code looks well and I think the problem is in another part of your project.

Comment: I would suspect your PluginsModel with the internalPointer to be at fault. Maybe I am wrong because I cannot see your implemenation. But I guess you let the internalPointer to point at the pointers stored in the QList. But when you add new plugins to the list, the complete QList contents can be copied into another memory. And then the pointers in the model might become obsolete. But as I say, I cannot see you implementation so I may be wrong.

Comment: Sorry can't prepare example now. I'll post it after tomorrow. Happy new year :)

Comment: @Dibo: no worries, take your time. Happy New Years to you, too!

Comment: Hi. Sorry for delay, big "after new year party" ;) . The problem was in my "add" function in model. Function should return QString but I didn't call return in this function, so that was a reason of crashing and strange errors while closing application. Now everything is working fine. Should I just delete this question?